# Nginx sends garbled bytes for any request

Tags: nginx, web-server

I have setup a new site on my Nginx server as a subdomain of another site on the same server. All my other sites still work perfectly fine but this new site simply sends over a bunch of random bytes as a response to any request with any path. There are no headers or anything in the response.

�����������А������   ������� ����������������

[see this for my nginx.conf.](https://termbin.com/vs3p) [And this one for my site config.](https://pastebin.com/gf2QnhMT) I honestly don't even know where to start with this one. There's nothing in the access log and nothing new in the error log. I have so little information.

I have tried removing the auto-indexing from the site config and putting an index.html in the web root but that's about it. Nothing else really comes to mind.

Comment: forgot to add links. Sorry! There we are.

Comment: please never use pastebin for showing up your config insert them into here directly

Comment: @djdomi ahhh sorry I thought it would be annoying to have a bunch of config stuff directly in the post. I kept all the comments and stuff so it's pretty long

Comment: The problem in posting critical question stuff on 3rd party sites is that they might disappear at any point, making the question incomplete in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration has these lines:

```
server {
    listen 80 http2;
    listen [::]:80 http2;
```

This means you are telling nginx to serve content using HTTP/2 over port 80. Since browsers don't have information that your server is using HTTP/2 on port 80, they connect using HTTP to the port, and they don't understand the response.

You need to use

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
```

in your config.

Comment: How come the browser doesn't know the server is using http/2? How do they normally tell?

Comment: Port 80 is a allocated for HTTP1 protocol. When browser connects to port 80, it always expects HTTP1 based server. Meanwhile, TLS connections are made over port 443, and there is a mechanism (ALPN) to tell what is inside the encrypted connection. Therefore browser can request either HTTP or HTTP/2 from the server during the TLS handshake. This means HTTP/2 is easiest to implement over TLS.

Comment: Ohh and that's why my other sites worked they had TLS set up already. Alright thank you so much!!